# Is there a way to tell where a pod was before it is migrated to another app node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to tell from which node a pod was before it was migrated or can we get the details of a pod which got migrated of its previous node/pod-name details?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Without any sort of logging system? No.

You need to setup logging or some kind or monitoring to do it. Basically this means that if you don't keep the history of what was happening in your cluster, you won't be able to tell.

K8s does not store the historical information. All you can do is to lookup the current state.

This means that you can check where the current pod are running, but you can not tell what happened to all the pods ever created since the creation of a cluster.